# Tropical lie algebra

Tags: tropical-geometry, tropical-arithmetic

In this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.01075.pdf are we mean that Lie semialgebras over semirings with a negation map is tropical version of Lie algebra?. And what we do when we define lifting? what is lifting mean in tropical algebra?